# Grub takes forever to show up

Tags: boot, grub2, mac, refit

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my MacBook Pro 5,3. Everything works fine so far except for GRUB. It takes 5-8 minutes to just show up. The rest of the boot process goes as expected. I'm also using refit.

I uploaded to output of `dmesg` and `bootinfoscript`. I really hope somebody has a solution for this.

[Output of `dmesg`](http://www.lightgraffiti.de/files/dmesg.txt)

[Output of `bootinfoscript`](http://www.lightgraffiti.de/files/bootinfoscript.txt)